# Python Web scraping with Requests Automated Login Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been attempting to web scrape a website using the python `requests` module and have needed to login to the site to retrieve the data I want. I have looked around everywhere but cannot find out why it is not working. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

login_url = "__withheld__"
target_url = "__withheld__"

login_data = { "username": "my_username", "password": "my_password"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    page = s.get(login_url)
    page_login = s.post(login_url, data = login_data)
    page = s.get(target_url)
    final_page = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    print(final_page.title)
```

This is the html of the password box:

```
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" class="metro-input" placeholder="Username" value="">
<span id="username-error" class=""></span>
<label class="ie789Only"> Password</label>
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="metro-input" placeholder="Password">
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="Sign in" id="button1" class="metro-button">
```

I believe that it may have to do with the website requiring the user to click the button though I could find no solution. I also tried looking for any post forms in the developer console when I login myself but have found no definitive form outlining the password/username. Any help is appreciated.

**Update** 
Here is the link to a site run by the same company (privacy) with the same security features if this is any help: https://ashwood-vic.compass.education/login.aspx?sessionstate=disabled

Comment: Can you post a link to the site? Might make it easier to know what you need to do to make this work

Comment: This is not the actual link (due to privacy) but is run by the exact same company and has the exact same security https://ashwood-vic.compass.education/login.aspx?sessionstate=disabled

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below code once

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
username = 'username of the site'
password = 'password of the site'

req = requests.get(login_url, auth=(username, password))
final_page = bs.BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')
print(final_page.title)
```

- Please refere this http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication

Comment: Unfortunately his didn't work although i've done more digging through the html code for the site and found that the site may use OAuth authentication although i'm not sure how to deal with that

Comment: The link is in the description